# Javascript calculations holding variables

Tags: javascript, variables, calculation

I'm exercising in javascript and i've made this script in order to calculate the sum of 2 variables and then use this sum in a third equation! any thoughts on how to make this work will be very useful!

```html
<form name="Calcultor" Method="Get" id='form1'>First Number:
    <input type="text" name="fnum" size="35" id="first">+ Second Number:
    <input type="text" name="snum" size="35" id="sec">
    <br>
    <br>Answer:
    <input type="text" name="ans" size="35" id="ans" />
    <input type="text" name="ans2" size="35" id="ans2" />
    <button type="button" onclick="Calculate();">Calculate</button>
</form>
<script lang="javascript">
    function Calculate() {
        var first = document.getElementById('first').value;
        var sec = document.getElementById('sec').value;
 var ans = document.getElementById('ans').value;

        document.getElementById('ans').value = parseInt(first) + parseInt(sec);
 document.getElementById('ans2').value = parseInt(ans);
        document.form1.submit();
    }
</script>
```

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

```js
function Calculate() {
    var first = document.getElementById('first').value;
    var sec = document.getElementById('sec').value;
    var ans = document.getElementById('ans').value;

    document.getElementById('ans').value = parseInt(first) + parseInt(sec);
    document.getElementById('ans2').value = document.getElementById('ans').value;
    /*document.form1.submit();*/
}
```

```html
<form name="Calcultor" Method="Get" id='form1'>First Number:
    <input type="text" name="fnum" size="35" id="first">+ Second Number:
    <input type="text" name="snum" size="35" id="sec">
    <br>
    <br>Answer:
    <input type="text" name="ans" size="35" id="ans" />
    <input type="text" name="ans2" size="35" id="ans2" />
    <button type="button" onclick="Calculate();">Calculate</button>
</form>
```

Feel free to ask, if anything isn't clear!

**Update (increment last input value by one):**

```js
function Calculate() {
    var first = document.getElementById('first').value;
    var sec = document.getElementById('sec').value;
    var ans = document.getElementById('ans').value;

    document.getElementById('ans').value = parseInt(first) + parseInt(sec);
    document.getElementById('ans2').value = parseInt(document.getElementById('ans').value) + 1;
    /*document.form1.submit();*/
}
```

```html
<form name="Calcultor" Method="Get" id='form1'>First Number:
    <input type="text" name="fnum" size="35" id="first">+ Second Number:
    <input type="text" name="snum" size="35" id="sec">
    <br>
    <br>Answer:
    <input type="text" name="ans" size="35" id="ans" />
    <input type="text" name="ans2" size="35" id="ans2" />
    <button type="button" onclick="Calculate();">Calculate</button>
</form>
```

You should use `parseInt()` before summing numbers, without parsed value you are summing `string` with `number`, and as expected, the result will be a string with one more character.

Comment: Thanks a lot! one more question if possible! if i insert +1 to this line document.getElementById('ans2').value = document.getElementById('ans').value +1; the script doesn't actually add +1 to the previous sum but instead it just puts this number after the sum. for example if 1+1 in first and second value i don't get with the +1 i added   3 as result but 21...

Comment: @ath_zach, I have updated the answer, is my explanation OK?

Comment: Thanks a lot again! yes it's working perfectly! i' ll exercise on that..

Comment: @ath_zach, nice to hear, that it helped you!

Comment: Hello again @Commercial suicide! i'm in trouble again with the same project, if you can help you'll save my day! thanks in advance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46404818/using-parantheses-around-variables-in-javascript-to-change-priority-in-math-calc?noredirect=1#comment79767265_46404818

Comment: yeap, but still can't figure it out! if possible check out the last line of code i found that the error is related with the division symbol / cause when i use other symbols +, - * etc instead of / its working... check at 4,95 / parseInt(document.getElementById('ans2').value)...