# Superscript Calculation Javascript Variables

Tags: javascript, variables, arithmetic-expressions, calculation

I'm exercising in calculations with variables using javascript and i can't figure out how to use superscripts in variables. With some help [Javascript calculations holding variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46392234/javascript-calculations-holding-variables/46392325?noredirect=1#comment79742544_46392325) i learned how to do calculations in general but my new question is how to use superscripts?

```html
<form name="Calcultor" Method="Get" id='form1'>First Number:
<input type="text" name="first" size="35" id="first">+ Second Number:
<input type="text" name="second" size="35" id="second">
 
<br>Answer:
<input type="text" name="ans" size="35" id="ans" />
<input type="text" name="ans2" size="35" id="ans2" />
<button type="button" onclick="Calculate();">Calculate</button>
</form>

<script>
function Calculate() {
    var first = document.getElementById('first').value;
    var second = document.getElementById('second').value;
 var ans = document.getElementById('ans').value;
 var ans2 = document.getElementById('ans2').value;
 
document.getElementById('ans').value = parseInt(first) + parseInt(second);
document.getElementById('ans2').value = 1.112 - 0.00043499 * parseInt(document.getElementById('ans').value)/*insert ans into a parenthensis*/ + 0.00000055 * parseInt(document.getElementById('ans').value)/*insert ans into a parenthensis and ^2 outside the parenthesis*/ - 0.00028826;

}
</script>
```

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: "_Superscript_" here means exponent?

Comment: Maybe [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) is what you want?

Comment: a yes!! thanks for the correction!

Comment: @ath_zach Use Math.pow()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function in javascript `Math.pow()`;

`Math.pow(2,4)` gives you 2^4 = 16.

```
Math.pow(2,4);
>16
Math.pow(2,4.1);
>17.148375400580687
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form name="Calcultor" Method="Get" id='form1'>First Number:
<input type="text" name="first" size="35" id="first">+ Second Number:
<input type="text" name="second" size="35" id="second">
 
<br>Answer:
<input type="text" name="ans" size="35" id="ans" />
<input type="text" name="ans2" size="35" id="ans2" />
<button type="button" onclick="Calculate();">Calculate</button>
</form>

<script>
function Calculate() {
    var first = document.getElementById('first').value;
    var second = document.getElementById('second').value;
 var ans = document.getElementById('ans').value;
 var ans2 = document.getElementById('ans2').value;
 
document.getElementById('ans').value = parseInt(first) + parseInt(second);
document.getElementById('ans2').value = 1.112 - 0.00043499 * parseInt(document.getElementById('ans').value) + 0.00000055 * Math.pow(parseInt(document.getElementById('ans').value), 2) - 0.00028826;

}
</script>
```

Updated Snippet according to answers works now!