# Using parantheses around variables in Javascript to change priority in math calculations

Tags: javascript, variables, parentheses, calculation

I'm exercising in javascript calculations using a combination of maths and variables and i'm finding a difficulty on using the right way parentheses. For example i want to do the following calculation `[(4,95/ans2)-4,5]*100` where ans2 is a calculated variable. In the last field i get 45.000 and i should take - 4.046 ... if the input in the first and second fields was 2 + 2

```html
<form name="Calcultor" Method="Get" id='form1'>First Number:
  <input type="text" name="first" size="35" id="first">+ Second Number:
  <input type="text" name="second" size="35" id="second">
 
  <br>Answer:
  <input type="text" name="ans" size="35" id="ans" />
  <input type="text" name="ans2" size="35" id="ans2" />
  <input type="text" name="ans3" size="35" id="ans3" />
  <button type="button" onclick="Calculate();">Calculate</button>
</form>

<script>
  function Calculate() {
    var first = document.getElementById('first').value;
    var second = document.getElementById('second').value;
    var ans = document.getElementById('ans').value;
    var ans2 = document.getElementById('ans2').value;
 
    document.getElementById('ans').value = parseInt(first) + parseInt(second);
    document.getElementById('ans2').value = 1.112 - 0.00043499 * parseInt(document.getElementById('ans').value) + 0.00000055 * Math.pow(parseInt(document.getElementById('ans').value), 2) - 0.00028826;
    /* in the following line i can't figure how to use with a proper way parentheses to prioriterize the calculations with the way i mentioned in the example before the code snippet*/
    document.getElementById('ans3').value = [( 4.95 / parseInt(document.getElementById('ans2').value)) - 4.5] * 100;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You cannot use `[ ]` as mathematical grouping operators; they simply don't work that way. Only `( )` parentheses work as mathematical grouping operators in JavaScript (and all other languages I can think of).

Comment: ok! but if i use ( ) instead of [ ] i get the same result! please check the comment in the last lines to see what i want to do!

Comment: @Pointy just FYI, racket and some implementations of scheme allow you to use square brackets instead of parentheses

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yes I figured there'd be a Lisp out there that allows `[ ]` :)

Comment: @ath_zach your code uses `parseInt()` all over the place, but the computations seem to involve lots of fractions. The `parseInt()` function is for **integers**.

Comment: The fact that you are getting an incorrect result doesn't allow you use arbitrary characters for grouping operations, most programming languages including JS only allow using `( )` for that. Also, you can achieve any grouping with `( )`, if you get incorrect results the problem is in another part of the code.

Comment: @Alberto Martinez the whole code works fine! i double checked it...

Comment: If you get incorrect results then is obvious that the whole code is *not* fine, what me an others are trying to say is that you can't solve your problem using `[ ]` because they are used for array access, not grouping operations (you can't just use anything you used in the school, programming languages have their own rules). For example, see the comment by @Pointy about `parseInt()`.

Comment: you can understand that by the whole code i mean everything before the commented line...

Comment: @ath_zach, please read the comments. Even if you did use [] in the way you want, it would not do anything different from using (). That is not your problem.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul thanks for the advice! as a newbie in programming it's difficult to understand what i do wrong without an example, but thanks to all anyway! i figured a solution on how to get the result that i want by seperating the math type in two pieces but again i want to learn how to use parentheses right in javascript calculations...

Comment: You use parentheses  for grouping in exactly the same way  you were taught at school. There's nothing unusual here.  Things in parens get evaluated then the value of that replaces the parenthesized expression

Comment: @Pointy can you please explain with more details about the parseInt() statement, because if i can judge right by your comments, using it "all over the place" it's not a good thing to do.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul you suggest also that the problem is in the rest of the code?

Comment: I suggest you learn how to use a debugger, step through the code, and see where it goes wrong.  All I am saying is there is no JS magic for parens

Comment: @ath_zach, did my answer solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was in this row: `document.getElementById('ans3').value = [( 4.95 / parseInt(document.getElementById('ans2').value)) - 4.5] * 100;`. You need to use `()` instead of `[]` for grouping and you also don't need to `parseInt` the value. Here is the working snippet:

```js
function Calculate() {
  var first = document.getElementById('first').value;
  var second = document.getElementById('second').value;
  var ans = document.getElementById('ans').value;
  var ans2 = document.getElementById('ans2').value;

  document.getElementById('ans').value = parseInt(first) + parseInt(second);
  document.getElementById('ans2').value = 1.112 - 0.00043499 * parseInt(document.getElementById('ans').value) + 0.00000055 * Math.pow(parseInt(document.getElementById('ans').value), 2) - 0.00028826;
  /* in the following line i can't figure how to use with a proper way parentheses to prioriterize the calculations with the way i mentioned in the example before the code snippet*/
  document.getElementById('ans3').value = ((4.95 / document.getElementById('ans2').value) - 4.5) * 100
}
```

```html
<form name="Calcultor" Method="Get" id='form1'>First Number:
  <input type="text" name="first" size="35" id="first">+ Second Number:
  <input type="text" name="second" size="35" id="second">
 
  <br>Answer:
  <input type="text" name="ans" size="35" id="ans" />
  <input type="text" name="ans2" size="35" id="ans2" />
  <input type="text" name="ans3" size="35" id="ans3" />
  <button type="button" onclick="Calculate();">Calculate</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks again! i really appreciate your kind gesture @Commercial Suicide for providing the whole code!